# Conditional Return from SQL Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, user-defined-functions

I am able to run this

```
  USE AdventureWorks2012;
    GO
    IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.GetJobData', N'IF') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetJobData;
    GO
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetJobData (@title NVARCHAR(25))
    RETURNS TABLE
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
    AS
    RETURN
    (
      SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalEmps
      FROM HumanResources.Employee
      WHERE JobTitle = @title
      GROUP BY JobTitle
    );
    GO
```

but I want to add some condition based on **@title** , so i want something like this.

```
      USE AdventureWorks2012;
        GO
        IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.GetJobData', N'IF') IS NOT NULL
        DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetJobData;
        GO
        CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetJobData (@title NVARCHAR(25))
        RETURNS TABLE
        WITH SCHEMABINDING
        AS
        RETURN
        (
WHEN (@title = 'Developer')
THEN
          SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalEmps
          FROM HumanResources.Employee
          WHERE JobTitle = @title
          GROUP BY JobTitle
ELSE
      SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalEmps
      FROM HumanResources.Employee
      WHERE JobTitle = @title+'Role'
      GROUP BY JobTitle

    );
    GO
```

But Not able to do it ... Can you help , I am using MS SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 2):

Handle `Case` statement at `where` clause like below. You are using sql server 2014 so you can use Concat function. Instead of `@title+'role'`. Added JobTitle also to make it more meaningful.

```
 IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.GetJobData', N'IF') IS NOT NULL
        DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetJobData;
        GO
        CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetJobData (@title NVARCHAR(25))
        RETURNS TABLE
        WITH SCHEMABINDING
        AS
        RETURN
        (

          SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalEmps,JobTitle
          FROM HumanResources.Employee
          WHERE JobTitle = Concat(@title,(CASE WHEN @title <> 'Developer' THEN 'Role' END))
          GROUP BY JobTitle)
END
```

Comment: To OP : Adding `JobTitle` to the `select` will make the result more meaningful.

Comment: @Prdp Yes adding Jobtitle will make more meaningful. But that is not part of function body so skipped it :).

Comment: It is for OP ;)

Answer (score 0):

Might not be as efficient as filtering in `Where` clause(Buddi's answer) but works well

```
SELECT JobTitle,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN ( JobTitle = @title
                      AND @title = 'Developer' )
                     OR ( JobTitle = @title + 'Role'
                          AND @title <> 'Developer' ) THEN 1
             END) AS TotalEmps
FROM   HumanResources.Employee
GROUP  BY JobTitle
```

**Note :** I have added `JobTitle` to the `select` to identify the count value for `JobTitle`